# Enviar parâmetros via GET em uma URL amigável

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Tenho uma página que a URL amigável é mais ou menos assim:
http://www.dominio.com.br/pt/produtos/

E a URL real é assim:
http://www.dominio.com.br/site/produtos/index.php?idioma=pt

Estou usando o IIS para desenvolver, então configuro as URLs amigáveis no web.config.
Quando acesso essa página:
http://www.dominio.com.br/pt/produtos/?q=teste

Funciona corretamente, a URL amigável funciona e o parãmetro enviado "q" aparece corretamente em minha programação em PHP.

Porém, quando envio para o servidor Linux, onde as URLs amigáveis são configuradas no htaccess, essa mesma URL:
http://www.dominio.com.br/pt/produtos/?q=teste

Até funciona carregando a página certa, mas não consigo recuperar o parâmetro "q". Alguém sabe o motivo?

No htaccess a regra esta configurada da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/produtos(/?)$ /site/produtos/index.php?idioma=$1 [NC,L]
```